# Why shadow clone technique make a clone of what they are holding?

Tags: naruto

**[Definition](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Shadow_Clone_Technique)** : Similar to the basic Clone Technique, Shadow clone technique creates copies of the user. However, these clones are corporeal instead of illusions.

According to me when Naruto uses Shadow clone technique then his whole dress also get cloned to other user, so there might be possibility that item inside bag might get cloned too.
And it can also be proved as he uses All direction shuriken technique where "Naruto and his shadow clones throw shuriken all at once." - [Source](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/All_Directions_Shuriken)

So the quesion is: How non-living object get multiplied because according to wiki definition about Shadow clone technique : "The user's chakra is evenly distributed among every clone, giving each clone an equal fraction of the user's overall power." but non-living object has no chakra so how come ?

If it is possible to use it which is true, then let us say that those cloned user threw kunai on the target then for sure it will get hit on that target. But if that cloned user (which uses that kunai) got vanish then :

Will that kunai too vanishes at that same time or it will be there as it is?

Comment: Normally what the shadow technique can do is hold back an idem with their shadows or manipulate them. I'm not sure if it can do more than that.

Comment: Well, obviously they are able to clone the equipment, as all the clones use the weapon, but actually I never understood it, because, if think logically, you can clone only the thing that has chacra, but clothes and weapon don't have it.

Comment: I'd go with the out-of-world explanation: if he can't clone shuriken, he shouldn't clone his clothes either, and mass nakedness shouldn't be a feature of his principle attack--just for jokes and special situations.    For in-world mechanics, no idea, there are very, very few such explanations for anything in Naruto.

Comment: Well we have seen Hiruzen Sarutobi's shadow shuriken technique,it explains a lot that chakra can be used to create anything,it's easier to make a copy of something although.

Comment: Because, Magic!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short answer**: If you enjoyed it, don't question the logic.

**Longer explanation**
This is an example of [Artistic License](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ArtisticLicense), which means the author is allowed to ignore logic if it makes the story more enjoyable.  The trope of a character's ability extending to their equipment is known as [My Suit Is Also Super](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MySuitIsAlsoSuper) on tvtropes.<sup>1</sup>

Cloning techniques in Naruto require this trope due to how it is usually used: to confuse, distract and deceive the opponent. Cloning based techniques would be useless if the opponent could tell the original apart from the clones by simply looking at who has a shuriken in hand!<sup>2</sup>

Artistic License requires [Willing Suspension of Disbelief](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/WillingSuspensionOfDisbelief) from the audience. This is acceptable to the audience since they want the story to entertain, and do not necessarily want it to be logically accurate. The author should maintain a balance between the Artistic License and the Willing Suspension of Disbelief that the audience is willing to give.

If he uses too much Artistic License, the audience cannot take him seriously anymore. For example, if Naruto had awakened Mangekyou Sharingan, and it was explained with "an Uzumaki can awaken Mangekyou Sharingan by repeatedly using Shadow Clones and Rasengan", then the audience will lose interest in the story.

It he uses too little of it, an opportunity to make the story more entertaining is lost. The author would have had to exclude a lot of techniques and events from the story, which would make it too boring.

---

<sup>1</sup> The trope of cloning techniques extending to the user's clothes is [Magic Pants](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MagicPants) is used mainly for censorship reasons, as otherwise the clones would end up naked. It is too much trouble for the author to keep dealing with all the time. Given how often the cloning techniques are used in the story, it would also get annoying for the audience after a while.

<sup>2</sup> Interestingly, in a much later battle, Kishimoto plays with this trope differently. Naruto makes one of his clones carry a certain thing which fools his opponent into thinking that clone is the original. See the below spoiler for details.

> During the battle against Kaguya Otsutsuki, Naruto deliberately places the Gudodama behind the back of one of his clones, which tricks Black Zetsu into thinking that clone is the original.

Comment: There exists shadow clone jutsu for Non living objects, See http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Shuriken_Shadow_Clone_Technique. Yin and Yang energies are extremely versatile, and can do just about anything so long as its not elemental.